# Any way to get a debit card as a minor without parent consent?

Tags: united-states, debit-card, minor

Yes, this question has been asked before, but never really answered. Most questions involve a **credit** card, which in this case I'm asking about a **debit** card.

Hi, I'm a 16 year old student facing some troubles at home. I develop software already, and am making a decent amount of money (almost more than my mom). The issue I'm having is that my mom thinks it's okay to take my money whenever she pleases, making up some excuse to justify her unjust actions.

Although this is an interpersonal issue, I'm looking to see if anyone knows if there is a chance of getting a reloadable debit card as a minor.

Yes, I am aware that since I am a minor, I am not allowed to enter legally binding contracts, however, I still have hope as I am looking for a debit card instead of a credit card, where the risk for the card issuer is a lot less.

I've looked into some alternative sources of debit cards such as cryptocurrency debit cards. The issue with these is that US regulations enforce them to verify my identity, and those who don't enforce this have had their cards revoked by the issuer because of political pressure.

I feel like there has to be some way of being able to have legal control over my money, as my parents do not respect my earnings and legally they have full rights to touch my money as it is a joint account.

Looking for any advice!

Comment: Is there anybody you that you have a trusted relationship (both ways) that can do it for you?

Comment: @WELZ Not anyone that is willing to get into a legally binding contract, that could put them in debt, on my behalf.

Comment: I'd recommend posting on the Law stack exchange to see if there's any kind of legal relief you can pursue; Not sure how legal it is for your parent to literally "take" your money. Perhaps you'd be able to sue her or something? I'd be interested in seeing the responses that show up there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't know of any way you could get a **DEBIT** card, there **may** be a way you can keep this money from your parents.

You can apparently open a **savings** account as a minor, without having your parents with you.

You can get deposits into a savings account from your software business. You may even be able to withdraw money from it on a limited basis, I believe you're allowed up to 6 withdrawals per month as a federal rule in the states.

Here's a link someone sent me on quora when I asked a similar question as a comment: https://www.wellsfargo.com/savings-cds/kids/

Apparently minors can open that savings account (And I'm now sure you could find others) without parents, but you'd need a drivers license / other good form of ID to do so.

If you open a savings account, you can withdraw your money either in person at the bank, or possibly at an ATM. Ask your local bank about this if they will let you open a savings account.

Comment: I'll check this out, you have any idea if I can get a card for this account though? I do have a state issued ID (not license) to prove identity, and for emergencies I have a passport as well.

Comment: Uh oh, another issue is that Wells Fargo doesn't have a branch/bank in my state (Massachusetts), let me see if there are any other banks that I can do this with.

Comment: Well, you'd be able to get an **ATM** card, but likely not a debit card, due to the transaction limit. The ATM route is still feasible, though; you still have the ability to get your money out if you need it.

Comment: Try finding a local community Credit Union and asking if you can open a savings account with them or a checking account without a parent. Credit unions are member-owned and most (if not all) I believe are non-profits; they work for their members and generally have better terms than banks (like lower fees and better interest rates). Perhaps you'll find one that's more lenient on the age thing, though I think the best you'd find is a savings account somewhere. Good luck

Comment: I second looking for a credit union. There are usually lower fees and my credit union didn't charge for unlimited withdrawals from some savings accounts.

Comment: The OP's concern is not whether they can get an account without their parents, but whether they can prohibit their parents from withdrawing money from it.

Comment: @Acccumulation the question's title disagrees with you; though their parents touching their money is the underlying reason they're looking for an account without their parents, overall, the question is concerning OP looking for an account he can get as a minor without his parents.

Comment: Question titles are summaries of the question. The body of this question makes it clear that their concern is with their parents withdrawing money.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you live.  I live in Canada, vancouver and Bank of Montreal let me opened my own account without my parents. If you go to the bank, you may be able to see.  Also, I was with PayPal for quite a while. Either way, you can also go to somewhere like money mart and get a cheque with your name on it.  I don't believe that your parents can check out a cheque in your name.

By the way, I live in Canada so cheque = check

Comment: Paypal is a good option but I doubt employers will pay to paypal accounts. Also Money Mart is not sustainable long term because the goal of OP seems to be to get paid into that account and be able to use it while keeping it out of reach of their mother.